# What is the specific and detailed immuned way to be protected from NoSQL injection on MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I know. There lots of guides, tutorials and questions at Stack overthere.
But this is not doing for fun, and I wont my projects will be hacked by another 15 years old kid due to some bad input he wrote, like:

```
{$ne: null}
```

and immidately will receive all of my users.

I am working with MongoDB and Node.js, with `mongojs` driver (see it here: https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs), from what I have tried, to put this input in a field text, it **does not** allow the attacker to receive the data - therefore, something in between already converting the data he added into text (I have tried this bymyself, with more than one syntaxes).

I also know about mongo sanitize plugin (search in github), but it is time consuming, and I want to focus on develop my project, instead of this waste of time on every endpoint, with a case of forget something and throw a full business to trash.

**My question (and for sure the question of many others):**

Is it enough to be safe from NoSQL injection?
Please, if it does not, tell what does, there must be a way to be 100% safe from NoSQL injections, otherwise, how Google, Facebook, Stackoverflow and other big sites are not got hacked by SQL/NoSQL injections?

Comment: Hmm, anyone? :)